# Why is this SQL query valid?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, subquery, correlated-subquery

Why doesn't this SQL query return ar error (in Oracle)?

`field_99` exists only in `table_1`!

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM table_1
 WHERE table_1.field_1 IN
     (SELECT table_2.field_1
        FROM table_2
       WHERE table_2.field_2 IN ('0000')
         AND (field_99 LIKE '%AAA%' OR field_99 LIKE '%BBB%' OR field_99 LIKE '%CCC%'));
```

If it is OK, must it return the same results as the following [correct] one?

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM table_1
 WHERE table_1.field_1 IN
     (SELECT table_2.field_1
        FROM table_2
       WHERE table_2.field_2 IN ('0000'))
   AND (field_99 LIKE '%AAA%' OR field_99 LIKE '%BBB%' OR field_99 LIKE '%CCC%');
```

I ran the first query and expected it would return an error.

Comment: Look up correlated subqueries. Query engines can do some clever stuff with scope, they aren't entirely bound to your parentheses.

Comment: It's good programming practice to _qualify_ all columns - at least when several tables are involved. E.g. `table_n.field_n` instead of just `field_n`.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? Why do claim it works? Presumably it works because that's how the language is defined. You need to say what your expectations & reasoning are with justification per documentation or an answer is just rewriting the manual with no idea what you do or don't understand or misunderstand. Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Comment: In case someone else runs into this situation: I have looked through similar questions and came to read how Oracle works with subqueries (Oracle - Release 19 - SQL Language Reference - Using Subqueries).
Here it is:
"Oracle resolves unqualified columns in the subquery by looking in the tables named in the subquery and then in the tables named in the parent statement."
All is clear now.
Thanks to those who helped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query works because the inner query gets the value of `field_99` from the enclosing row in the outer query.

Since there's no correlation between the `field_99` value and any value coming from the inner query, it's indeed pointless (not outright wrong, as you noted, the query works, but pointless).
You can safely rewrite the query as you suggested, and IMHO, it would also be easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you @Mureinik, you really answered the question and helped.